# Can I legally sell an XNA game made with Visual C# Express Edition?

Tags: xna, c#, legal

I've dowloaded Visual C# Express Edition and when it starts up it says "for evaluation purposes only." What does this mean?

Does this mean I have to buy the full version to legally sell my game I make with it? Or can I just use the free express edition? I really dont want to make a game and then find out I can't sell it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can.

See this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969484/can-i-produce-a-commercial-application-using-visual-studio-express-2010

There was an FAQ for the 2008 edition with a line that explicitly said that yes, you can. It's hard to dig up anything conclusive for 2010, but Microsoft actively goes around encouraging developers to download Express edition and sell their applications developed with it.

The reason that Visual Studio Professional and up cost money is because they offer features like plugin support, project management, and testing tools. Their primary customers are large companies with complicated development environments. They couldn't care less about indie developers using their compiler and IntelliSense without paying.

To get rid of the "Evaluation Only", you need to register your copy.

Answer (score -3):

Read the license. As far as I know, the 2010 express editions *do* allow commercial use, unless the license has changed.

Comment: -1 This answer is essentially saying: "You should check. I think you can, unless you can't." Not very helpful and I can't put much confidence in it.